# actionscript 3 ULscrollBar Issue!

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, scrollbar

I am trying to create a scrollBar for my MC which contains several mc horizontally. I wanted to apply ULscrollBar for my MC container so I can scroll for move small MC but I couldn't get it to work...I would appreciate if someone can help me about it. (there is no scroll head for me to drag...) Thanks...

[alt text http://popslinger.org/scroll.jpg](http://popslinger.org/scroll.jpg)

```
   cont=new videoCont();
    cont.x=_x;
    cont.y=_y;
    addChild(cont);

    var mySb:UIScrollBar = new UIScrollBar(); 

    mySb.direction = "horizontal"; 
    mySb.setSize(cont.width, 25);  

    mySb.move(cont.x, cont.y+cont.height); 
    mySb.scrollTarget=cont; //the black container....
    addChild(mySb);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the image you posted, the content isn't wide enough to be scrolled. In that case, the scrollbar will appear but without a visible thumb and won't respond to clicks.